# A question about mxnet - MXNetError: Check failed: delay_alloc:

Tags: graph, deep-learning, mxnet, dgl

I am studying GNN and trying to follow and study some code samples. What i am looking at is [Detecting fraud in heterogeneous networks using Amazon SageMaker and Deep Graph Library | AWS Machine Learning Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/cn/blogs/machine-learning/detecting-fraud-in-heterogeneous-networks-using-amazon-sagemaker-and-deep-graph-library/).

I am trying to implement this by plain python environment instead of amazon sagemaker. By following corresponding [github repo](https://github.com/awslabs/sagemaker-graph-fraud-detection/tree/master/source/sagemaker), i have finished the data processing part to proceed to model training part. But when i start train the model, it just throw

MXNetError: Traceback (most recent call last): File “…/src/ndarray/ndarray.cc”, line 507 MXNetError: Check failed: delay_alloc:

I am doing it on paperspace gradient ML platform with A5000 machine while using CUDA 11.6 (Actually i am not using GPU yet). mxnet and dgl version are 1.9.1 and 1.0.2 correspondingly.

Anyone knows what potential reason to cause this?

I already tried to change the version of mxnet but it still not work.